# Android Sqlite using java how to compute distance on query

Tags: android

I have longitude and latitude on my database and got some ideas on getting current longitude and latitude using GPSTracker. I want to compute for the distance on my query and sort it by nearest places. thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: i also want to know how to retrieve values from a column and send it to a variable if i used SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not for providing you with code for what you want but to help you if you run into problems with your code.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21063893/2556111